# Unity C# - Is infinite loop thread terminated when class is destroyed?

Tags: c#, multithreading, class, unity-game-engine

So I have a game object that contains a class A (extends monobehavior) that contains(creates) a class B (no monobehavior).  This class B spawns a thread that contains a while (true) loop which does some work.

My question is...

When this GameObject is disposed/destroyed , I assume the class B contained inside of it is destructed as well. When this class B is destructed, is this infinite loop thread terminated as well?

Comment: Only if the Dispose cancels it. For that reason, you should never write a infinite loop. Always have it use a variable or other method to allow cancelation.

Comment: So i would need to override dispose and just set that variable? Or would that work in the destructor (~)?

Comment: I would put that in the Dispose. Cleanup like that is what it is there for, after all. But actually writing a proper Dispose is not that easy. Nevermind the issue of not accidentally swallowing Exceptions. And how you cancel it, realy depends on how you started it in the first place. There are several ways to skin that particular feline. | How certain are you, that you need a Thread? Is the work CPU bound? If not, a simple async might work just as well.

Comment: I started the thread like new Thread(myfunc).Start().  This is totally a CPU bound only computation for path finding that does not rely on Unity specific objects. However; it is not a total spinlock. Even though i have a while(true).. i also use a semaphore to block most of the time.
However; since it doesnt extend from MonoBehaviour can I even override Dispose?

Comment: Every class can implement IDisposeable. It is a .NET or even GarbageCollection feature, not a Unity or Mono special. Monobehavior is a asbract base class. And one thing those often do, is be a "gathering of interfaces".

Answer (score 0):

Threads that have been started, principally run until the main thread ends. This is a OS level fallback, to avoid Zombie Threads without a owning application. However, it is not a fallback you should rely on. A Thread once started should be seen as a unmanaged resource, so cleanup code should be in place. The Dispose pattern in particular.

There is this [wonderfull article on how to do it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose), but I feel it needs a explanation. You generally have to differentiate two cases with the Dispose pattern:

1. **You are working with a Unamanged resource directly**. In that case you write the Finalizer first. Then provide Dispose as a convenient way to clean stuff up on a programmers decision.
2. **You are handling or may be handling something that implements IDisposeable.** In that case, all you implement is the Dispose part and for the sole purpose of cascading teh call down to the Disposeable stuff you wrap around.

95% of all classes only implement IDisposeable because of case 2. We do not know if there actually is anything Disposeable, or if that was just part of a abstract base class.

[Thread does not implement Dispose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread) (I have no idea why), so you got a rare case 1. Dispose and Finalizer are often also compressed into one method - usually the Dispose one - as their code is very similar. The only real difference between Finalize and Dispose is cascading behavior:

- When Finalizing, you never cascade. Finalisation is between this instance and the GC.
- When Disposing, you always cascade (when possible). Most of the cases it is only there to allow cascading.

My final advice is, that since you are working with Multithreading you have to take care not to swallow Exceptions. Normally you got to write really bad code for to swallow Exceptions, but with Multitasking you have to go out of your way to *not* swallow any. I can not find any indication that Thread has a build in mechanic to persist exceptions (I know for a fact that Task does). All I can give you is the two articles on exception handling I link often:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/
- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET